# SPSS Statistics Analysis report confusion

Tags: spss

I have **151190** records of a table. and i have to analyze the data on **SPSS**. after the analysis i have some results. **Mean**=74617.92 with **standard error**=871.744, **Median**=94118, **variance**= 1393725134, **Standard Deviation**= 37332.628, **Minimum**= 1353, **Maximum**= 95085, **Skewness**= -.007, **Kurtosis**= -1.31. 
I cannot understand the relation why there is a huge gape between mean and variance.

Comment: The more relavant comparison is between the mean and the standard deviation, not the variance. But in any case this question is off topic here - we deal with programming questions, for statistical questions please go [HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: thanks for your help. I am very thankful to you.